# SetParameter in NativeQuery with tsVector

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, entitymanager

I have a native query with some values and I want to get these values with setParameter, but if I try I get an error, that my resultset cant extract. Here my code:

```java
query1 = 
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("
    SELECT id 
    FROM user 
    WHERE to_tsvector('simple',cast(name AS text)) @@  :value ");

query1.setParameter("value", "'"+parts[i + 1].toLowerCase()+"'" );
```

**Also I tried** (but still with error: Could not locate named parameter [value], expecting one of [] ):

```
query1 = 
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("
    SELECT id 
    FROM user
    WHERE to_tsvector('simple',cast(name AS text)) @@ ' :value'");

    query1.setParameter("value", parts[i + 1].toLowerCase());
```

Also I tried with positional parameter:

```
query1 = 
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("
    SELECT id 
    FROM user
    WHERE to_tsvector('simple',cast(name AS text)) @@ ' ?1'");

    query1.setParameter(1, parts[i + 1].toLowerCase());
```

Same error as named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Named parameters are not supported by JPA in native queries, only for JPQL. You must use positional parameters. Try something like
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM employee where employeename = ?1");
q.setParameter(1, "test");

Comment: I tried, but same error. I guess it's about the vector parameter.

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. The query works, but i want to do with setParameter to prohibit SQL-Injections.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked my query and finally I can use .setParameter.

```
SELECT id
FROM user
WHERE to_tsvector('simple',cast(name AS text)) @@   
plainto_tsquery('simple',cast(:value AS text))"

query1.setParameter("value", parts[i + 1].toLowerCase());
```